# What is the gauge boson mass term for a theory with a matrix of scalars?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

If we have a theory with gauge group $SU(3) \times SU(2)$ with a set of six complex scalar fields grouped in $\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}
a & d\\
b & e\\
c & f
\end{pmatrix}$, where, for instance, the fields b and f acquire a VEV, how can we write the mass terms for the gauge bosons?

I know that in the Standard Model this can be done by adding to the Lagrangian a term of the form $(D_\mu \Phi)^\dagger D^\mu \Phi$, but in this case this term would give a $2\times 2$ matrix and the Lagrangian must be a scalar.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I was supposed to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the trace and that would produce a scalar. That's similar to what one does when one works with scalar fields in the adjoint representation.

To be more explicit, let $U\in SU(3)$ and $V\in SU(2)$. Then under a gauge transformation the transformation laws for $\Phi$ are

$$\Phi \rightarrow U \Phi V, \qquad D_{\mu}\Phi \rightarrow U\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right) V, \tag{1} $$
$$\Phi^{\dagger} \rightarrow V^{\dagger} \Phi^{\dagger} U^{\dagger}, \qquad \left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger} \rightarrow V^{\dagger} \left( D_{\mu}\Phi \right)^{\dagger} U^{\dagger}. \tag{2} $$

Then the trace of the kinetic term in your question transforms as
$$ Tr \left[\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger} \left(D^{\mu}\Phi\right) \right]\rightarrow Tr \left[ V^{\dagger}\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger} U^{\dagger} U \left(D^{\mu}\Phi\right) V \right]=Tr \left[\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger} \left(D^{\mu}\Phi\right) \right],$$

where we have used the cyclicity of the trace and the fact that $UU^{\dagger}=\mathbb{I}$ and $VV^{\dagger}=\mathbb{I}$.

**Edit:**

In order to arrive at the covariant transformation laws in (1) and (2), let's consider the action of the covariant derivative on $\Phi$. $$D_{\mu} \Phi = \partial_\mu \Phi + A_{\mu} \Phi +\Phi B_{\mu},$$ where
$$A_{\mu} = A_{\mu}^a \lambda^a, \qquad \qquad B_{\mu}= B_{\mu}^i \tau^i,$$
and $\lambda^a\in SU(3)$, $\tau^i \in SU(2)$. The gauge fields $A_{\mu}$ and $B_{\mu}$ transform "oppositely" in some sense, since they act on the left and right, respectively
$$A_{\mu} \rightarrow \left(U A_{\mu} U^{\dagger} - \partial_{\mu} U U^{\dagger} \right), \qquad \qquad B_{\mu} \rightarrow \left(V^\dagger B_{\mu} V -  V^{\dagger} \partial_{\mu} V \right).$$

Then $D_{\mu} \Phi$ transforms as follows
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu \Phi &+ A_{\mu} \Phi +\Phi B_{\mu} \rightarrow \partial_\mu 
 \left( U \Phi V\right) + \left(U A_{\mu} U^{\dagger} - \partial_{\mu} U U^{\dagger} \right) \left(U \Phi V\right) + \left(U \Phi V\right)  \left(V^\dagger B_{\mu} V -  V^{\dagger} \partial_{\mu} V \right)\\
&=U \Phi V+\color{red}{\underline{\partial_{\mu}U (\Phi V)}} + \color{blue}{\underline{(U \Phi) \partial_\mu V}} + U A_{\mu}\Phi V -\color{red}{\underline{\partial_{\mu} U (\Phi V)}} + U\Phi B_{\mu} V - \color{blue}{\underline{(U \Phi) \partial_{\mu} V}} \\
&= U\left(\Phi + A_{\mu} \Phi + \Phi B_{\mu} \right) V=UD_{\mu}\Phi V,
\end{align}

where the underlined coloured terms cancel with their respective colour.